# Streaming a file as a field of Json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to send some big text file, says 10 Megabyte over internet, as a field of a Json Object. Somthing likes:

```
{
   "status":0,
   "fileContent":<File content comes here>
}
```

I must write it in Java+Jackson Json. It is easy to read the whole file into a String. I have tried and it works. But, are there any method to stream the content of the file as a field of a JSON Object? Because some file can become larger, says up to max. 20 MB.

Comment: Where is the problem of the String-Solution? Up to 20MB is eally not a problem for the RAM capacities, and you have to process the whole file anyways.

Comment: This is really bad idea to send file content as JSON. I assume that you have REST API. You should create in this API one method for retrieving metadata about file and one method for retrieving stream to the file. You can also provide additional parameters to this API method - for example: start reading from byte number 23101, etc.